# Передача экземпляра класса в процедуру Dev С++

Tags: c++

Возникла необходимость передачи экземпляра класса в процедуру.
Использую Dev C++.

Примерный код:

```
ClASS exepml; //создаем экземпляр класса ClASS
Fill_exemlp(exepml); //передаем наш экземпляр в процедуру.
.....

void Fill_exemlp(exepml) //процедура получает наш экземпляр
{
....
}
```

но тут нужно указать ТИП аргумента в процедуре "Fill_exemlp", который у нас экземпляр класса.
Как это сделать?

Comment: А что Вы хотите?

       void Fill_exemlp(ClASS exepml)
       // или
       void Fill_exemlp(ClASS& exepml)

Comment: *Интересная у вас нотация для имен классов)*

Comment: @chudo116, не забывайте принимать верные ответы!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А в чем проблема написать что-то вида

```
void Fill_exempl(ClASS& exepml) //процедура получает наш экземпляр
{
    exepml.test();
}
```

Comment: Собственно, так передавать разумнее всего. Ведь в этом случае в функцию попадет не сам объект, а лишь ссылка на него.